# How to pass selectors or html tags between components in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular6

Suppose that I have an html selector: book-table.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'book-table',
  templateUrl: './book-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-table.component.css']
})
```

How do I pass this from component to html so I can use it as a custom directive ?

for example if I could pass the selector in component as below

```
...
  this.cards.push(
      { title: 'Card 1', cols: 2, rows: 2, table:<book-table></book-table>} 
    );
...
```

I should be able to use it on html

```
...
  {{card.table}}
...
```

giving the same result as

```
...
  <book-table></book-table>
...
```

Comment: As your component is exported , you can use your selector of the component in any html page directly as custom directive `<book-table></book-table>` . Why you want to pass it inside an array?

Comment: I'm using material dashboard & want to bind material-data tables in different cards within the dashboard area.